# MFC ownerdraw menu size

Tags: mfc, cmenu

I'm wondering how I can set the size of an ownerdraw CMenu using his own text.

Looking at the documentation:

```
void CColorMenu::MeasureItem(LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT lpMIS)
{
   // all items are of fixed size
   lpMIS->itemWidth = COLOR_BOX_WIDTH;
   lpMIS->itemHeight = COLOR_BOX_HEIGHT;
}
```

But using this approach I have the same size for all the menus. 
How I can have dynamic dimension of the menu and submenu as for the standard windows menu?

Comment: CItemCont* vIt = (CItemCont*)lpMIS->itemData;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to identity the item you want to draw by the given information in the MEASUREITEMSTRUCT. Just read the docs ind the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647558(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Owner_Drawn_Menus_and_the_WM_MEASUREITEM_Message).

You receive this message for each item in the menu.